Custom context propagation between services
I am currently trying to figure out a way to propagate custom heavy context objects between services. I have a complex service chain and from the beginning to the end a custom context must be propagated alongside the traceId that is linking the requests between the microservices.
I just don't know how to approach this, I am using spring-boot-starter SDK and from what I read I can maybe use Baggage somehow? I can't find a single example how to do anything like this in Java/Spring boot.
For example let's say I will have a JSON metadata object that I want to propagate alongside the traceId. Currently the auto instrumentation adds a Kafka header:
{
    "traceparent": "00-c29c309f729efe0ee54a5114837b3592-3786ae7af42304d0-01",
    "__TypeId__": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode"
}

Can I somehow include MDC values as well? Something like:
{
    "traceparent": "00-c29c309f729efe0ee54a5114837b3592-3786ae7af42304d0-01",
    "MDC":{"key": "val,"key2": "val2"}
    "__TypeId__": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode"
}

My goal is to have it easily maintainable  so I am hoping to be able to use something out of the box just like how the traceparent is auto propagated.
